# Android Kotlin - viewBinding Import unresolved reference on views

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I followed multiple tutorials on how to implement this new nonsense.

I removed

```
apply plugin: `kotlin-android-extensions`
```

from gradle, added:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

and then in activity (not MainActivity but another one because it's the first one that creates error on rebuild):

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
```

totorials are showing that the views have to be used this way now:

```
binding.whatEverView
```

but I still have `unresolved reference` on those views.

Now I'm wondering if the correct class gets automatically imported which is:

```
import de.blaa.blaaaa.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
```

None of the tutorials are showing what actual class supposed to be imported so is this the correct one? What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try clean & rebuild of Android Studio? Sometimes the issue is just the studio :)

Comment: Yes it's the first what I did

Answer (score 0):

Check that the id of "whateEverView" doesn't have a leading underscore or something.

In my case, I found that my field had an id of "**_what_ever_view**" in the layout xml.  Changing it to "**what_ever_view**" fixed it.

Not sure if the problem is limited to leading underscores, or even if it's a specific version of the plug-in, but it does appear to be a bug.  In my case, the issue field appears totally valid during code editing (code completion knows about the field), but the "unresolved" issue appears during build time.